# Return probability of a SRW in an even number of steps

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, random-walk, stochastic-analysis

I am looking for some references for the following problem.

> Consider a graph $G$ and a simple continuous time random walk $(X_t)_{t\geqslant 0}$ on this graph. Consider the family of events $(e_t)_{t\geqslant 0}$ where $e_t$ is the event $\{X_t$ has jumped an even number of times$\}$ and the family $(o_t)_{t\geqslant 0}$ the event for odd number of jumps. What is a sharp bound for the following quantity:
>
> $$G(x,t)=\mathbb{P}_0(X_t=x\cap e_t)-\mathbb{P}_0(X_t=x\cap o_t)$$
>
> Where $\mathbb{P}_0$ means the probability measure given that the random walk is starting from 0.

**Trivial examples:**

On $\mathbb{Z}$, if $x$ is at even distance of the origin then the walker had to make an even number of steps to be at that position at time $t$ and we have: $$G(x,t)=\mathbb{P}_0(X_t=x\cap e_t)=\mathbb{P}_0(X_t=x)\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt t}$$

If we add loop with rate 1 on each site and $x$ at even distance of the origin then:
$$G(x,t)= e^{-t} [\cosh(t)\mathbb{P}_0(X_t=x)-\sinh(t)\mathbb{P}_0(X_t=x)] = e^{-2t}\mathbb{P}_0(X_t=x)$$

I am looking for references for this type of question for less trivial graph such as the triangular graphs. For various reasons, in the triangular graphs, it should look like:
$$G(x,t) \sim  e^{-4t} \mathbb{P}_0(X_t=x)$$

If you can prove it or give me references, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should wait at least five more days before posting this again somewhere else, but this seems like it might be better suited for math overflow (mathoverflow.net) since it seems like an open research problem.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will post there my question in a few days.